# Jdbc settings for connecting to Impala

Tags: jdbc, hive, impala

What is the combination of driver and jdbc URL to use for CDH5 (I am on CDH5.3)?

I have tried a few including:

```
jdbc:hive2://myserver:21050/;auth=noSasl
```

And with the following driver:

```
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

I have added

```
   /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/impala/lib/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/*
```

to the classpath (but still no success)

The result is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2://myserver:20150/;auth=noSasl
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you're using the correct driver. You should use the [Impala JDBC driver](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/impala/jdbc/impala-jdbc-v2-5-16.html) (rather than the Hive driver).

Then you should be able to use the `com.cloudera.impala.jdbc3.Driver` driver with a connection string like: `jdbc:impala://host:21050`

The [Impala JDBC driver guide](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/connectors/latest/PDF/Cloudera-JDBC-Driver-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf) has more details and examples.

Comment: Bottom link is dead.